# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document for the drop down list - python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have written selenium chrome driver script for an ASP.net website and got the `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` error while running it.

script suppose to click one by one item from the drop down list. There is total 4 drop down list and working like this when the page is load first drop down has options when we click on the second option of the first drop down after some time page loads data into the second drop down and same procedure for others so by this below code i can able to select second, third, forth.... option of first drop down and then got error while selecting second option of second drop down

here is the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def selectYear():
    year = driver.find_element_by_id("carYear")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(year).click(year)
    year.click()
    WebDriverWait(year, 100).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//option[2]")))
    yearOptions = year.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for option in yearOptions:
        optVal = option.get_attribute("value")
        if optVal is 0:
            continue
        else:
            print("Car Year is : %s" % optVal)
            dataList['Year'] = optVal
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).click(option)
            option.click()
            selectModel()

def selectMake(driver):
    make = driver.find_element_by_id("carMakeId")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(make).click(make)
    make.click()
    WebDriverWait(make, 100).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//option[2]")))
    makeOptions = make.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    print makeOptions
    for option in makeOptions:
        optVal = option.get_attribute("value")
        if optVal == '0':
            continue
        else:
            print("Make is : %s" % optVal)
            dataList['Make'] = optVal
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).click(option)
            option.click()
            selectYear()


def main():
    driver.get("https://www.getunitronic.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "carMakeId")))
    selectMake(driver)
# driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataList = {'Make' : "Make",
                'Year' : "Year",
                'Model' : "Model",
                'Engine' : "Engine",
                'Category' : "Category",
                'Product Type' : "Product Type",
                'Title' : "Title",
                'Stock Power' : "Stock Power",
                'Octane' : "Octane",
                'HP' : "HP",
                'LB-FT' : "LB-FT",
                'Desctiption' : "Description",
                'Installation' : "Installation",
                'UniCONNECT+' : "UniCONNECT+",
                'Features' : "Features",
                'Price' : "Price",
                'Media1' : "Media1",
                'Hardware Included' : "Hardware Included",
                'Recommended Software' : "Recommended Software",
                'Related Hardware' : "Related Hardware"}
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    sys.exit(main())
```

Error :

```
Make is : 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\unitronic.py", line 121, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File ".\unitronic.py", line 96, in main
    selectMake(driver)
  File ".\unitronic.py", line 85, in selectMake
    selectYear()
  File ".\unitronic.py", line 52, in selectYear
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//option[2]")))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 63, in __call__
    return _find_element(driver, self.locator)    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 402, in _find_element
    raise e
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591         (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
makeOptions = make.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
print makeOptions
for option in makeOptions:
    optVal = option.get_attribute("value")
    if optVal == '0':
        continue
    else:
        print("Make is : %s" % optVal)
        dataList['Make'] = optVal
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).click(option)
        option.click()
        selectYear()
```

to

```
options_count = len(make.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"))

print makeOptions
for i in range(0, options_count):
    option = make.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")[i]
    optVal = option.get_attribute("value")
    if optVal == '0':
        continue
    else:
        print("Make is : %s" % optVal)
        dataList['Make'] = optVal
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).click(option)
        option.click()
        selectYear()
```

Elements in element collection will become stale once they are changed. So you need to get the elements again when you face such issues